# A family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exist an infinite family of functions which satisfy

$|f^\prime(x)|=1$ and $f(1)=f(-1)=0$?

where 
a) $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$
b) $f$ is a complex function defined on some open neighbourhood of the closed unit disc in the plane.

Comment: $|f'(x)| = 1$ everywhere? At one point? Where exactly?

Comment: Yes, constantly as a complex function.

Comment: Can you answer a)?

Comment: So you're interested if its true in case a) or in case b)?

Comment: You should have an idea at least of what goes wrong with (a) by trying to sketch a picture.  For (b), because of existence of "$f'(x)$" I guess you are talking about complex differentiability.  For such $f$, $f'$ is also complex differentiable.  Do you know which complex differentiable functions (on a connected open set) have constant modulus?

Comment: Hint for (a): Rolle's theorem.

Comment: For (b), domain containing $\pm1$ would suffice instead of open neighbourhood of the closed unit disc